# shell_exec() not executing pdftotext command

Tags: php, shell-exec, pdftotext, xpdf

I installed the required library and its working in terminal but not in my php file.
My code is :

```
$mypdf = shell_exec('/usr/local/bin/pdftotext test.pdf test.txt');
echo $mypdf;
```

If I execute this command `/usr/local/bin/pdftotext test.pdf test.txt` in terminal it works fine.

I also write my code this type :

```
shell_exec('/usr/local/bin/pdftotext test.pdf test.txt');
$mypdf = file_get_contents("test.txt");
echo $mypdf;
```

In Error Log the message is :

```
/usr/local/bin/pdftotext: /opt/lampp/lib/libgcc_s.so.1: version `GCC_4.2.0' not found (required by /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6)
```

Comment: Can you please expand on what do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: This command creates a test.txt file from test.pdf if run from terminal.

Comment: And it does not create this file if run inside the php file?  See my answer below.

Comment: Can you please advise on where did you install the pdftotext library from?\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have some trouble with a dependency. Check your `error.log`. Find out which file is missing and add it to the path environment variable of your php installation.

Comment: only '/usr/local/bin/pdftotext: /opt/lampp/lib/libgcc_s.so.1: version `GCC_4.2.0' not found (required by /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6)' error in the error_log

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that you're expecting `$mypdf` to contain the PDF document instead of the return value of the executed command.  If you're trying to print out 'test.txt', then you'll need to load it up and print it.

Comment: Or do something like `$mypdf = shell_exec('/usr/local/bin/pdftotext.exe test.pdf /dev/stdout');`

Comment: my command should create `test.txt` file in current directory but it is not creating. I check this issue that is related to mine "http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-254155.html" but didn't help me

Comment: use my code like this also `shell_exec('/usr/local/bin/pdftotext.exe test.pdf test.txt');
$mypdf = file_get_contents("test.txt");
echo $mypdf;`

Comment: @SumitMadan Are you sure that the working directory of the php being executed is the same as when you ran it manually?  It may not be able to find 'test.pdf' in the working directory.

Comment: i ran this command `shell_exec('mkdir test');` and it is creating the directory in current directory.

Answer (score 1):

Issue was: `/usr/local/bin/pdftotext: /opt/lampp/lib/libgcc_s.so.1: version 'GCC_4.2.0' not found (required by /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6)`

And the solution was to rename `/opt/lampp/lib/libgcc_s.so.1` to `libgcc_s.so.1.bak` and solves my problem. But confusion is that what was the issue in it :P